# WiFi often freezes after 17.04->17.10 upgrade

Tags: wireless, upgrade, dell, 17.10

After upgrading 17.04 to 17.10, my wifi keeps freezing (without actually disconnecting) about once an hour.  Turning WiFi off/on in the upper right corner fixes the issue.  Dell XPS 13

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       logical name: wlp58s0
       version: 32
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.13.0-16-lowlatency firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4-00022-QCARMSWPZ-2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:287 memory:dc000000-dc1fffff
```

Comment: If you're affected by this bug, please report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1743279, so Ubuntu devs can soon fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been reported on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1743279
If you're affected, please tell them in the bug report so they can fix the bug ASAP.

The `firmware-6.bin` file needs to be updated. Ubuntu currently ships version `WLAN.RM.4.4-00022-QCARMSWPZ-2` and the fix for this issue was released in version `WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00051-QCARMSWP-1`, which means you need some version later than the latter for the card to work properly on >4.12 kernels.

As of today, this bug can be fixed by simply replacing the `board-2.bin` (not actually required but recommended) and `firmware-6.bin` files with what's currently in the upstream repository for `linux-firmware`, or by grabbing the `firmware-6.bin` from kvalo's repository for the proper version.

Another answer here gave the correct diagnose and procedure, but used an incorrect version of the firmware to be downloaded.

You can grab the correct version from kvalo's repository, which is guaranteed to always work (if you don't require the new `board-2.bin` as well).

These commands below will automate the replacement of the files:

```
$ sudo wget https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/raw/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/4.4.1/firmware-6.bin_WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00051-QCARMSWP-1 -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-6.bin
```

Alternatively, you can grab the files from the current state of `linux-firmware`
These commands below will automate the replacement of the files from what's upstream (notice these commands might work now but there's no guarantee they will work in the future because the repository's contents can change, although they will hardly ever break things like this).

```
$ sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
$ sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-6.bin -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-6.bin
```

Then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with DELL XPS PP25L (Fresh installation of 17.10). Restarting the network-manager service solves the problem temporally, but I wouldn't want to put a cron to restart the service each 15 minutes.

By default, one previous similar problem  was solved by adding the following lines to the NetworkManager.conf file

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

But now, these lines are already there by default, at least in my fresh installation.

Comment: Yep, I have that line too. Please upvote to raise awareness.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue solved by updating the firmware file:

- From [firmware page](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k/firmware?s%5b%5d=qca6174) follow the `QCA6174` link to [ath10k-firmware - QCA6174/hw3.0/4.4.1](https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/4.4.1)
   (that's the latest at this point), and download the recently updated [firmware-6.bin_WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00051-QCARMSWP-1](https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/4.4.1/firmware-6.bin_WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00051-QCARMSWP-1)
- Replace `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-6.bin` with the downloaded file:

```
$ sudo -s
# cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/
# mv firmware-6.bin firmware-6.bin.old
# mv ~/Downloads/firmware-6.bin_WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00051-QCARMSWP-1 firmware-6.bin
```

- Reload wifi

```
# rmmod ath10k_pci
# modprobe ath10k_pci
```

Comment: That's not the best firmware to fix this issue. The fix has been made available in version WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00051-QCARMSWP-1.

Comment: If you're affected by this bug, please report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1743279, so Ubuntu devs can soon fix it!